# how to change the color of one colum of the jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I want to change the color of one column of the `jqgrid` to red, but I don't know how to make it?

How to change the color of the data in this column to red?

Answer (score 0):

Read this article. Should solve your problem.
http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/jqgrid-set-a-fixed-background-color-for-an-entire-column/